# Is there way a to pass URL values in html files in django templates using constant substitution?

Tags: django, html, python-3.x, django-templates

This is Django problem. I am a newbie to this.
This is my url.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from splunkAutomation.logic.Constants import Constants
from . import views

app_name = 'splunkAutomation'
urlpatterns = [
 path(Constants.URL_FOR_SEEING_ALL_SPLUNK_QUERIES,views.viewForSeeingAllSplunkQueries, name=Constants.NAME_OF_URL_FOR_SEEING_ALL_SPLUNK_QUERIES),
]
```

I want to be able to reference this name "`Constants.NAME_OF_URL_FOR_SEEING_ALL_SPLUNK_QUERIES`" in html template.

The following is the snippet from the html file

```
    <ul class="actions">
    <li><a href="{% url 'splunkAutomation:splunkQuerySpecific' query.id  %}" class="button special">Check</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Basically I want to use the constant substitution instead of `{% url 'splunkAutomation:splunkQuerySpecific' query.id  %}`

Is there a way to use this ?

Answer (score 0):

I you add a name to the path:

```
path(Constants.URL_FOR_SEEING_ALL_SPLUNK_QUERIES,views.viewForSeeingAllSplunkQueries, name="url_link"),
```

You can use it like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'url_link' query.id  %}" class="button special">Check</a>
```

If you want to have a dynamic url, you can do this (example for class based views):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(
        regex=r'^(?P<webaddress>\w+)/$',
        view=Mysite.as_view(),
    ),
)
```

And in your view you grap the parameter:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.webaddress= kwargs.get('webaddress', '')
```

In your template you can then access the value with

```
{{ view.webaddress }}
```

Comment: Hi @ger.s.brett, Thanks for the quick response.                         The constant 'name=Constants.NAME_OF_URL_FOR_SEEING_ALL_SPLUNK_QUERIES' has the value 'splunkQuerySpecific'. The reason i don't want to use it the you mentioned is because "Suppose if the name changes, then i will have to change it in all the places where its being referred (like in a href tag above). However if I refer it (if possible) by using 'Constant. NAME_OF_URL_FOR_SEEING_ALL_SPLUNK_QUERIES' at all the places then even if the name changes, the rest of the code will remain still neat and tidy. :)

Comment: But why would the name change? Names of URLs are constants.

Comment: Hi @DanielRoseman, For example, the functionality of a given page (like the above display all the splunk queries) in application changes (tomorrow I might want to add some resolution functionality to the same page), then in that case i would want to change the name of URL accordingly to give the reader some better context of what the page does.

Comment: This is not how you should do this (your solution will always demand server restart): if you want to do this dynamically you should catch the last part of the url and hand this over to the view - you would capture this part of the url as a parameter.

Comment: oh okay @ger.s.brett Guess its not a great use case. Anyway just to be clear, could you please elaborate when you say "your solution will always demand server restart" and "catch the last part of the url".

Comment: see edit above. The urls.py is just loaded on start of the django (production) server. Only the dev server loads it from time to time anew.

Comment: Oh okay. Got it. The new edit is helpful. I will try to implement it. Thank you :) .